# Select COUNT in two table in one query with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way i can select the COUNT with two table with one single query.

At the moment i have the following and it doesn't work correctly.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(t1.id) as t1_amount,
COUNT(t2.id) as t2_amount
FROM
table1 t1,
table2 t2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select (select count(*) from table1) as t1_amount,
       (select count(*) from table2) as t2_amount
```

Here is another way:

```
select t1.t1_amount, t2.t2_amount
from (select count(*) as t1_amount from table1) t1 cross join
     (select count(*) as t2_amount from table2) t2
```

Your method does not work because the `,` in the `from` clause does a `cross join`.  This does a cartesian product between the two tables.

Comment: Thanks Gordon which method is more efficient?

Comment: @bluebill1049 . . . They should be the same in terms of efficiency.  Personally, I prefer the second approach because I tend to avoid `select` in `select` statements.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, i will follow your advice

Answer (score 2):

As they are two separate queries and you want them in the same result set, use a UNION:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `table1_total` FROM `table1`)
  UNION
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS `table2_total` FROM `table2`);
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua for the answer