# Creating a table with number of records of other tables

Tags: sql, count

I would like to create a table `RECORDS_COUNT` with 2 columns `TABLE_NAME` and `COUNT` which displays the number of rows of 5 tables:

`TABLE1`, `TABLE2`,.. `TABLE5` and `POP-TOTAL`.

For example:

```
TABLE-NAME |  COUNT
 ----------------------

TABLE1     |  200 
----------------------
TABLE2     |  100  
----------------------
TABLE3     |  200 
----------------------
TABLE4     |  350 
--------------------- 
TABLE5     |  150  
----------------------
POP-TOTAL      |  1000
```

These numbers will change everyday and I need to access the results quickly without having to open the 5 tables.

Comment: Sample data and desired results are a big help for others to understand what you want to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far? are you able to write a query which extracts the row counts?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Let's say the database is called `population`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've left my old answer below for interest, but I think this addresses your question more accurately:

```
SELECT 
[TableName] = so.name, 
[RowCount] = MAX(si.rows)
into #temp
FROM 
sysobjects so, 
sysindexes si 

WHERE 
so.xtype = 'U' 
AND 
si.id = OBJECT_ID(so.name)
and so.name in ('TABLE1', 'TABLE2', 'TABLE3', 'TABLE4', 'TABLE5') 
GROUP BY 
so.name 

select * 
from #temp
union all
select 'POP-TOTAL', (select SUM([RowCount]) from #temp)
```

This will produce the results you want in a temporary table. Then sum them up and display them.

Old answer:

This may not work for you if the format is important, but there is an answer here:
[Select COUNT in two table in one query with MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072876/select-count-in-two-table-in-one-query-with-mysql)

It might put you on the right track.

```
select (select count(*) from table1) as t1_amount,
       (select count(*) from table2) as t2_amount,
       (select count(*) from table1) + (select count(*) from table2) as Total
```

With this method you would have a column per table, plus one for the total.

Its not the most efficient, but if you are just looking to check each day, it should do the job.

Output:

```
t1_amount | t2_amount | Total
-----------------------------
1121      | 544       | 1665
```

Comment: Thank you Iconiq. Can anyone add the answer for a display in 2 columns and the tables in the row?

Comment: Could you match the names used in the example? Thank you Iconiq.

Comment: Do you mean the table names I've used? As in the line `and so.name in ('TABLE1', 'TABLE2', 'TABLE3', 'TABLE4', 'TABLE5')`

Comment: Yes please to match the examples. This way command vs given names can be identified